# Запятые после слова «думал»

Tags: запятые

Давно мучает вопрос, ставится ли запятая после «думал» в некоторых случаях. Например, отвечаю на сообщение «Думал(,) дойду», а запятая выглядит как-то неуместно, но мысленно можно поставить союз «что» и запятая становится уместной. Ставить ее или нет, если мысленно можно союз поставить в таких предложениях, как: *думал дойду, думал надо будет, думал это кошка*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Да, строго запятая нужна во всех случаях, как вы верно отметили, потому что подразумевается "что".* Поэтому я бы допустил её непостановку только в крайних случаях, например, в такой переписке, где идёт упрощение: может не быть заглавных букв в начале предложения, может отсутствовать точка в конце целого (обычно последнего) предложения, где опускаются порой кавычки и некоторые даже имена собственные пишут с маленькой буквы (хотя я сам последнее не очень приветствую). А вообще, найдутся люди, которые против таких упрощений, поэтому им предлагать такого не буду.

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогли.

Answer (score 2):

Это неполное СПП, причём неполное в обеих своих частях (пропущены "Я" и "что"). У Розенталя рассматриваются частные случаи, когда та или иная часть СПП неполная (§ 33, п.2, 1/, 2/). При этом запятая не ставится (исключая устойчивые фразеологизмы) **только** когда придаточное укорочено до одного *союзного слова* (относительного местоимения или наречия. § 33, п.4, 3/):

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137

В нашем случае остался *член предложения* (дойду), пропущено же союзное слово "что". Соответственно, здесь запятая **нужна**.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!